# Best way to format changes to data frames?

Tags: python

I've got this looooooong and unsightly code that will probably get longer. I'm not asking for to solve a problem, but for insight on the best way to format this.

```
# Create data frames.
channel_data = pd.DataFrame(result_channel_statistics, columns=[
    'result_playlist_id' ,
    'result_channel_name' , 
    'result_channel_views' ,
    'result_channel_subscribers' ,
    'result_channel_total_videos' 
    ])
video_data = pd.DataFrame(video_details, columns=[
    'result_video_id' ,
    'result_video_upload_time' , 
    'Published Date' ,
    'Published Time' , 
    'result_video_name' , 
    'result_video_description' , 
    'result_video_views' , 
    'result_video_likes' , 
    'result_video_comments' 
    ])

# Data Frame Structure
channel_data['result_channel_subscribers'] = pd.to_numeric(channel_data['result_channel_subscribers'])
channel_data['result_channel_views'] = pd.to_numeric(channel_data['result_channel_views'])
channel_data['result_channel_total_videos'] = pd.to_numeric(channel_data['result_channel_total_videos'])
upload_time = video_data.groupby('result_video_upload_time', as_index = False).size()
published_date = upload_time['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(upload_time['result_video_upload_time']).dt.date
published_time = upload_time['Time']  = pd.to_datetime(upload_time['result_video_upload_time']).dt.time
video_data['Published Date'] = published_date #Pull date from string
video_data['Published Time'] = published_time #Pull time from string
# Rename column headers
video_data.columns = ['Video ID', 'Published', 'Uplaod Date', 'Upload Time', 'Video Title', 'Video Description', 'Views', 'Likes', 'Comments']
channel_data.columns = ['Video ID', 'Channel Title', 'Total Views', 'Total Subs', 'Total Videos']
```

I feel like the easiest way is to simply toss it into a function, but I was curious if you all had some better way to present all of this:

```
# Data Frame Structure
channel_data['result_channel_subscribers'] = pd.to_numeric(channel_data['result_channel_subscribers'])
channel_data['result_channel_views'] = pd.to_numeric(channel_data['result_channel_views'])
channel_data['result_channel_total_videos'] = pd.to_numeric(channel_data['result_channel_total_videos'])
upload_time = video_data.groupby('result_video_upload_time', as_index = False).size()
published_date = upload_time['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(upload_time['result_video_upload_time']).dt.date
published_time = upload_time['Time']  = pd.to_datetime(upload_time['result_video_upload_time']).dt.time
video_data['Published Date'] = published_date #Pull date from string
video_data['Published Time'] = published_time #Pull time from string
# Rename column headers
video_data.columns = ['Video ID', 'Published', 'Uplaod Date', 'Upload Time', 'Video Title', 'Video Description', 'Views', 'Likes', 'Comments']
channel_data.columns = ['Video ID', 'Channel Title', 'Total Views', 'Total Subs', 'Total Videos']
```

Is there a chance I can include some of these changes into the data frame creation list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of following 3 lines,

```
channel_data['result_channel_subscribers'] = pd.to_numeric(channel_data['result_channel_subscribers'])
channel_data['result_channel_views'] = pd.to_numeric(channel_data['result_channel_views'])
channel_data['result_channel_total_videos'] = pd.to_numeric(channel_data['result_channel_total_videos'])
```

you can do this because there are duplicates.

```
columns_to_change_type = ['result_channel_subscribers', 'result_channel_views', 'result_channel_total_videos']

for col in columns_to_change_type:
    change_type_to_numeric('result_channel_subscribers')
```

change_type_to_numeric function is follows.

```
def change_type_to_numeric(col_name):
       channel_data[col_name] = pd.to_numeric( channel_data[col_name])
```

This is an example. Try to reduce duplicates as much as possible.

Other than that, use constants for column names in a config class like this.

```
class Configs():
       RESULT_CHANNEL_SUBS_COL = 'result_channel_subscribers'
```

and you can use this with `Configs.RESULT_CHANNEL_SUBS_COL` instead of the column name. These are some clean code strategies.

Instead of following 4 lines in your code,

```
published_date = upload_time['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(upload_time['result_video_upload_time']).dt.date
published_time = upload_time['Time']  = pd.to_datetime(upload_time['result_video_upload_time']).dt.time
video_data['Published Date'] = published_date #Pull date from string
video_data['Published Time'] = published_time #Pull time from string
```

You can use this.

```
pub_dttm = pd.to_datetime(upload_time['result_video_upload_time']).dt

video_data['Published Date'] = upload_time['Dates'] = pub_dttm.date
video_data['Published Time'] = upload_time['Time']  = pub_dttm.time
```

Answer (score 0):

You could decide to keep your definitions (nickname, destination name, transformations) in some tidy arrays.

First, some synthetic data for sake of example:

```py
# synthetic data
result_channel_statistics = [
    [1, 'foo', '30', '10', '200'],
    ['2', 'bar', '25', '5', '50'],
]
video_details = [
    [1, '2022-12-05 01:23:45', 'hello', 'descr', '5', '2',
     ['best movie ever', 'ok but not great']],
    ['2', '2022-12-11 09:08:07', 'world', 'descr', '11', '3',
     ['this was great', 'I fell asleep']],
]
```

Then, definitions:

```py
def numeric(s): return pd.to_numeric(s)
def timestamp(s): return pd.to_datetime(s)
def date(s): return pd.to_datetime(s).dt.date
def time(s): return pd.to_datetime(s).dt.time
def identity(s): return s

def process(df, d):
    df = df.copy().set_axis(pd.unique([k for k, *tail in d]), axis=1)
    for src, dst, fun in d:
        df[dst] = fun(df[src])
    return df[[dst for src, dst, fun in d]].copy()
```

Application:

```py
dchan = [
    ('id',            'Video ID', numeric),
    ('name',     'Channel Title', identity),
    ('views',      'Total Views', numeric),
    ('subscribers', 'Total Subs', numeric),
    ('n_videos',  'Total Videos', numeric),
]

dvid = [
    ('id',                   'Video ID', numeric),
    ('t',                   'Upload At', timestamp),
    ('t',                 'Upload Date', date),
    ('t',                 'Upload Time', time),
    ('name',              'Video Title', identity),
    ('description', 'Video Description', identity),
    ('views',                   'Views', numeric),
    ('likes',                   'Likes', numeric),
    ('comments',             'Comments', identity),
]

channel_data = process(pd.DataFrame(result_channel_statistics), dchan)
video_data = process(pd.DataFrame(video_details), dvid)
```

Result:

```py
>>> channel_data
   Video ID Channel Title  Total Views  Total Subs  Total Videos
0         1           foo           30          10           200
1         2           bar           25           5            50

>>> channel_data.dtypes
Video ID          int64
Channel Title    object
Total Views       int64
Total Subs        int64
Total Videos      int64
dtype: object

>>> video_data
   Video ID           Upload At Upload Date Upload Time Video Title  \
0         1 2022-12-05 01:23:45  2022-12-05    01:23:45       hello   
1         2 2022-12-11 09:08:07  2022-12-11    09:08:07       world   

  Video Description  Views  Likes                             Comments  
0             descr      5      2  [best movie ever, ok but not great]  
1             descr     11      3      [this was great, I fell asleep]  

>>> video_data.dtypes
Video ID                      int64
Upload At            datetime64[ns]
Upload Date                  object
Upload Time                  object
Video Title                  object
Video Description            object
Views                         int64
Likes                         int64
Comments                     object
dtype: object
```